# pause page before redirecting back

Tags: php, javascript, html, wordpress

I'd like to make a certain WordPress page pause for a few seconds before redirecting back to the page the visitor was on. The scenario is a redirect page after successful submission of a form. It will say 'form submitted successfully' or the like for a few seconds, and then redirect back to the page the visitor was on. The redirect is just a simple browser back functionality --

```
<script type="text/javascript">history.go(-1);</script>
```

-- in the head, which is easy to add to just that specific page with a custom field. But what can I add to make the page pause for a few seconds before going back? Bear in mind that this is a WordPress site with lots of posts so I can't use some kind of body onload redirect back to a specific post with `window.location = "the-post-or-page-visitor-was-on";`. I need to use the browser's back history to just take the visitor back -1 to whatever page or post they were on, but just pause for a few seconds before doing so.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you can, use flashes (messages that disappears after some time) instead of redirect. Easier, nicer, requires less requests, etc.

Comment: @erenon, yeah, I'd like to do something like that, but it's so complicated when using a WordPress plugin to hack it to do that. I originally just wanted it to ouput a success message to a hidden div, but I can't find a way to do that so far and have the form complete its action. And without knowing AJAX, I've just decided on this sort of clunky solution for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [`window.setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.setTimeout
  (
    function() { history.go(-1); },
    1000 // 1 second
  );
</script>
```